# how to interpret this 'sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n' command

Tags: bash

I have a question about how to interpret the following sort command line, which is used for sorting the bed file acording to column 1(chromosomes), column 2(staring position) and column 3(end position) of the bedfile:

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n foo.bed
```

The above command does not work the way I want for sorting the first column. In response to the responders questions, I attached some of my tested command and results, I tested the following file(test.bed):

```
Ch2     50      100
Ch10    100     110
Ch11    110     120
Ch21    120     150
Ch21    20      80
Ch1     100     110
Ch1     50      100
```

both the following two command line does not work

```
sort -k 1,1n test.bed
sort -k1,1n test.bed
```

and both results are:

```
Ch1 100 110
Ch1 50  100
Ch10    100 110
Ch11    110 120
Ch2 50  100
Ch21    120 150
Ch21    20  80
```

Only the following command work the way I want

```
sort -k1,1V test.bed
```

and the result is:

```
Ch1 100 110
Ch1 50  100
Ch2 50  100
Ch10    100 110
Ch11    110 120
Ch21    120 150
Ch21    20  80
```

Comment: Take a look: https://explainshell.com

Answer (score 1):

Take an instance of following data

```
62, 10, 3
6, 10, 37
62, 2, 72
55, 22, 5
```

If I do sort on the data on the basis of key 1(first column), I observe the following results:

```
sort -k1

62, 10, 3
6, 10, 37
62, 2, 72
55, 22, 5
```

Note the order of 62, 6, 62 and 55. 
If I want numerical sorting on the basis of key1, I can do

```
sort -k1 -n
6, 10, 37
55, 22, 5
62, 10, 3 
62, 2, 72
```

Note, that data is sorted here till the end of the line on the basis of key1. If I want numerical sorting on the basis of key1, then key2; I can do

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n
6, 10, 37
55, 22, 5
62, 2, 72
62, 10, 3 <== The position of this row has changed, 
              because when data of first row was same,
              sorting is done on the basis of 2nd column.
```

As per man sort:

> ```
>  -k field1[,field2], --key=field1[,field2]
>          Define a restricted sort key that has the starting position field1, and optional ending position field2 of a key field.
> ```
>
> The -k option may be specified multiple times, in which case
>   subsequent keys are
>                compared when earlier keys compare equal.  The -k option replaces the obsolete options +pos1 and -pos2, but the old notation is
>   also supported.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear and concise! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> -k, --key=KEYDEF
>   sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type

and also (emphasis mine):

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and **stop position**,
>   where **F is a field number** and C a character position in the field;
>   both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.
>   If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted
>   from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.  **OPTS is one or more
>   single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global
>   ordering options for that key**.  If no key is given, use the entire
>   line as the key.  Use --debug to diagnose incorrect key usage.

and also:

> -n, --numeric-sort
>   compare according to string numerical value

So, `-k1,1n` means "sort by the field 1 alone (not continuing to end of line), and use numeric comparison for that field". Only `-k1` would take the entire string from that field to the end of the line; not desirable when you want to sort numerically.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your explanation, but I am still confused, I tried the command and it produces very weird result. Instead,  when I use:

Comment: sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n -k 3,3n

Comment: Then, it worked, I am still very confused about the expression.

Comment: I can't comment on "weird result" and "worked" if you provide no input, no actual output and no expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've updated the question. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: `"Ch1"` is not a number, so it makes no sense to use `-k1,1n`. If you always have `"Ch"` and some number, `-k1.3,1n` would make sense for the first column (sort by the first column numerically, starting from the third character). `-k1,1V` also works because it kind of looks like a version number (version numbers ignore prefix).

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. It now become crytal clear!!